# WinRT and Desktop App bundle?

Tags: mobile, windows-8, windows-runtime

I want to create a desktop app that comes bundled with a WinRT install and sell it on the app store.

How can I do this? The idea is that when you install the desktop app and you're on windows 8, it will also install the Metro version of the app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LOB Windows Store Apps can be sideloaded - and that would probably the only way to bypass the Windows Store. Be aware that there are some guidelines and restrictions that you might want to have a look at before you do that, fore example here:

[Windows 8 Sideloading Requirements (from TechNet)](http://blogs.technet.com/b/scd-odtsp/archive/2012/09/27/windows-8-sideloading-requirements.aspx)

So in theory (because I haven't tried this) you should be able to sideload a non-windows store app and a windows store app at the same time- but packaging them together for the windows store is not possible. As far as I know you can't have a Windows Store App that installs a non-windows store app,- as these apps aren't supposed to have access to the system like that.

Comment: I guess this is about as close as you'll get. TYVM, Iris.

Answer (score 2):

You can sell Desktop app on Windows store but it won't reside on Microsoft Servers. They'll certify your application and list the app on the store but for users will be redirected to your site for download.

Also you won't be able to package WinRT and Desktop application together.

[Listing your desktop app in the Store](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsstore/archive/2012/06/08/listing-your-desktop-app-in-the-store.aspx)

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this also answers the question, I just think Iris got a bit closer to doing what I needed.